# Why isn't the throughput = (1 / response time) by their definition?

Tags: queueing-theory

I found that all say that **throughput is inversely proportional to response time**. But I found it's confusing that if I see their relationship by their definitions, isn't each of them a reciprocal of each other?

From my point of view, if I define them by my intuition, it then goes:

**Throughput**: Number of task completions per time unit = $\frac{Completion}{T}$ 
**Response Time**: time cost from task's arrival to its completion = $\frac{T}{completion}$

where $T$ is the total observation time.

What did I miss? Why can't I say that $Throughput = \frac{1}{Response Time}$?

Comment: Because of parallelism? A car factory may spit out a new car every minute even  though the production of each car takes hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found my bug,

The mean response time should be $\frac{\text{Total Response time of all jobs}}{completion}$, and every job has a different $Response\ Time$ due to the queueing delay.

This is the main observation that it can't be the reciprocal of throughput, and especially in the parallelism case.